# Visual Studio 2017 не открывает исходник разработанный на версии VS 2010г

Tags: c#

как исправить?
что делать?
куда бежать?

Comment: Открыть в 2015 студии, пересохранить, открыть в 2017. Обычно помогает.

Comment: Опишите какой тип проекта открываете и конкретные симптомы. Студия выводит какую-то ошибку? Зависает? Ничего не происходит?